# Close dialog box and child form and pass result to main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have C# windows form that open a child form, in it I have textbox, OK and Cancel buttons,

When user clicks OK I check the connection to the machine user entered in the textbox.
If connection is OK I want to close child form, if not show a Yes\No message asking if user still want to use the entered machine name.
If answer is Yes close the child form, if not just close the Yes\No question.

In the main form I’m checking the child dialog DialogResult but can't seems to make it work since this.Close pass Cancel result. Here is the code in the main form:

```
DialogResult result = SetServer.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // BLA
}
```

Code on child form

```
if (!PingMachine(testmachine))
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(“No connection", "Check", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    else
    {
        btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do not use Close in a Modal form. Just set the this.DialogResult property with the appropriate value

Comment: Have you tried to use this.Hide(); before closing the form? It keeps your child form hidden and perform any operation before close. If you click "NO" you can just this.Show();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the results of the child form instead:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(“No connection", "Check", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes) {
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
else {
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
}
```

Setting the DialogResult of a modal form will automatically close it, too, so no need to call `this.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

I was searching something else, and stumbled with this post. Even though it is almost a year old, I want to add something if anyone else comes to this post.

If you want to close only the `YesNo` dialog when user press `No`, then you need to do absolutely nothing with the code for the `No` option. By default, whichever button is pressed, windows will close the `YesNo` dialog, you just need to hardcore the actions you want to take when each button is pressed, but if you do not want to perform any action at all, just don't write anything at all.

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{ 
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 
} 
// End your code here. If user press "No", then the question will automatically close with no actions being executed.
```